# Ajax new Request error Uncaught TypeError: send is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I called ajax and my ajax have this error:
 **Uncaught TypeError: ajaxGetData.send is not a function**
My code this is:

```
 <button onclick="myFunc()" class="btn btn-default">Click</button>
  <div id="getRes"></div>
 <script>


  function myFunc(){ 

    var ajaxGetData = new Request({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      'item1':'item 1',                                               
      'item2':'item 2'                                               
      },
    onRequest: function(){
        document.id('getRes').innerHTML = '<div>is Loading...</div>';
        },
    onSuccess: function(responseText){                                                            
    if(responseText){  
        document.id('getRes').innerHTML = responseText; 
    }else{ 
        document.id('getRes').innerHTML = '';       
    }    
   },
    onFailure: function(){}
  });
  ajaxGetData.send();
  }

 </script>
```

What is my problem? tank you.

Comment: What is this Request object? Show us code for this....

Comment: You are combining aspects of jQuery and regular XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 2):

You messed [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with [javaScript Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request).

A modified and running version of your code with js Request can be:

```js
function myFunc() {

    var ajaxGetData = new Request('https://api.github.com/repositories?since=364');
    ajaxGetData.method = 'get';
    fetch(ajaxGetData).then(function (responseText) {
        return responseText.json();
    }).then(function (responseText) {
        if (responseText) {
            document.getElementById('getRes').innerHTML = responseText.map(function(ele, idx) {
                return ele.id;
            });
        } else {
            document.id('getRes').innerHTML = '';
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunc()" class="btn btn-default">Click</button>
<div id="getRes"></div>
```